# Chat application using socket programming (Erlang) in php

Tags: php, jquery, sockets, erlang, chat

I have implemented a chat application using jquery, mysql and php and it is requesting the server more than 100 times for a certain interval of time and log file completed. The processing of the remaining site is very slow. Please suggest to me how to implement the chat application using socket programming and php.

I found the link here http://code.google.com/p/mypeb/

I want to follow the application using Erlang. When I searched on google I found some code PEB ( PHP - Erlang Bridge) extension but how can we install that extension in localhost ( WAMP - Windows XP ) system.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to show some code, or ask a more detailed question: At the moment, this is way too broad to find a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

php/mysql aren't the right tools for the job.
if i were you i'd be looking into Erlang or at least php/memcached

Comment: I would change that to PHP/MySQL Aren't the *best* tools for the job.

Comment: Agree with Robert - and I'm far from convinced that Erlang and/or memcached improve the situation any

Comment: facebook's chat is developed in Erlang, enough said

Answer (score 1):

for optimise your system research for HTTP

[http keep alive connections](http://www.mtdev.com/2002/09/http-keep-alive-connections-in-php)

[real time notifications in php](http://php.dzone.com/news/real-time-notifications-php?mz=30309-phpwindows)

for more efficients use
[node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: I'd have given this +1 were it not for the node.js recommendation: for much more (system) efficiency write it in assembly language - but its not always a pragmatic or practical solution to switch languages

Answer (score 0):

The best chat application in Erlang is [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/), which, luckily, now has [http-bind](http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_http_bind) feature.

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used solutions I see right now are:

**Faye** - node.js and ruby

**socket.io** - node.js and ports available for various other languages

**SockJS** - erlang, node.js, ruby

**SignalR** - .NET

**XSockets** - .NET